# VBA / VB.Net: Searching For Spaces and Numbers Using The Like Operator

Tags: vb.net, string, excel, sql-like, vba

I'd like to use the like operator in vb.net to find numbers.
I have written a function which is given formulas to analyse.
It needs to return `TRUE` if the formula contains numbers.
Given that numbers also exist in worksheet names, functions, and cell references it is tricky.

I have got the function almost finished however I need one last bit of code.

Using the like operator I want to write a statement that will look for constants in the string and the constant will also be proceeded with a space `" "` and followed by a space `" "`.

For example I want the like statement to return true on the following:

```
if " 'Essbase P&L'!$A:$BG,H$5 CBS_Act13 12345 " like "* [0-9] *" then
' Do Action Here
```

The number `12345` or other constants will always have a space directly before AND after.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you are asking is exactly what regex is for.  http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet  Have fun posting your regex question next, I'm out!

Answer (score 0):

You Can:

- Split()
- Using Regex:

  ```
  Dim Str = " 'Essbase P&L'!$A:$BG,H$5 CBS_Act13 12345 "
  If Regex.IsMatch (Str, " (\d*) ") Then
  ```

Comment: But doesn;t the \d* look for any character? I need it to look only for numbers (which might include decimals) proceeded and followed by a space